# Android app crash on action item add

Tags: android, crash, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I've been developing an app with an ActionBar and no initial action items on it (just the overflow dots). After a while I decided to implement a search icon so I've update my /res/menu/main_activity_actions.xml like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:orderInCategory="1"
      android:showAsAction="always"/>
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

I've also update the main activity (which extends ActionBarActivity) with the onCreateOptionsMenu().

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Problem is that this code never shows the action_search icon at all, instead it puts always in the corresponding "title" in the overflow menu list. 
I thought the problem was the attribute "showAsAction" since I'm using the support library so I've updated it to:

```
<menu
 ...
 xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ...
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    ...
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    myapp:showAsAction="never"/>
 </menu>
```

This little modification make the app crash at startup and I don't understand why! 
The error is like

"E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: blabla.blabla.bla.appname, PID: 29450
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView ..."

with a long line of library errors without a code reference.

Any tips? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:orderInCategory="1"
      app:showAsAction="always"/>
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
       app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Comment: it continues to crash on startup.. it's like the first modification I've done. :S

Comment: Post the MainActivity code with the onCreateOptionsMenu method

Comment: the create method is this:

@Override

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

Answer (score 0):

I do see that your XMLNS tag is weird. In your first example you used: `xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

But in the your code change second example you used `myapp:showAsAction` and then not `android:showAsAction`. The `yourapp`/`myapp` or whatever doesn't matter too much as long as it matches across the whole file. But you need both, because the custom XML tag namespace thing is only used on pre-Honeycomb support library usage. The `android:showAsAction` needs to be there for 3.x and newer.

Try:

```
<menu ... xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ...
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    ...
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:showAsAction="never"
      myapp:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Though I'm not sure if that will cause a crash or not.  If you're running on 3.x or newer then the crash may be related to missing resources or something in your activity code.

Comment: If I use the "android:showAsAction" Android Studio suggests me that I should use "myapp:showAsAction" in order to meet compatibility with appcompat. The minimum SDK is 16 though I'm running the app on a Nexus4 Lollipop, anyway using them both seems not to resolve the problem :(

Comment: @mystigate Hrm, I'm not sure then. We use both in Eclipse and it works on all devices we've tested from 2.3 to 5.0. I don't think it gives us any LINT errors to use both. But either way, I don't think having those or not should cause it to crash. Is your activity extending a custom base class that super.onCreateOptionsMenu is doing some work in?

Comment: the MainActivity extends an ActionBarActivity(appcompatV7) and implements a FragmentChanger. In the main onCreate() the supportActionBar is created and set. The "super.onCreateOptionsMenu" call is there in order to secure the process when a fragment will kick in but right now its doing nothing.